# Dell Inspiron 1525 Battery not working (Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: 10.04, dual-boot, battery

I am using ubuntu 10.04 on dell N5010 with perfect battery but it get immediately hibernate after removing power cord. battery is charing during ubuntu use.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out battery status in setup by hitting F2 in boot menu? 
Did you see your battery's health in Windows. I am running Dell 1545 and Dell 1525 both with Ubuntu as primary. I also ran into battery related problems recently. Replacing it solved the problem.

It is almost certainly a hardware issue. Get a new  battery.